# awk regex number of repetition {n} doesn't work on mawk version 1.2

Tags: regex, awk

Is there a workaround to be able to check for patterns of type

```
/[pattern]{n}/
```

where n is the number of repetitions in [mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/mawk.html) version 1.2.

This is available in newer versions and with the GNU awk.
I'll need this to work with the different versions of awk.

Comment: Which variant of `awk` is at version 1.2?  If what you're using doesn't support what has been required since the days of yore (for example, all of the current millennium), then you're on a hiding to nothing.  Get a version that is vaguely cognizant of the standard (which was promulgated around 1992 — the first version of POSIX 1002.2 which covered the shell and utilities such as `awk`).

Comment: if `n` is small, just repeat the pattern that many times.

Comment: It's mawk. The script that I'm going to write could be used in different systems, that's why I'm searching for a workaround.

Comment: The current version of `mawk` is 1.3.3, but it looks like even that does not support the `{m,n}` repeat notation — it seems to be a blind-spot in its interpretation of POSIX Extended Regular Expressions. Either don't write your code with repeats, or insist on an `awk` other than `mawk` or work out how to do the repeats. For a fixed number, simply repeat the previous pattern. For a range `{m,n}`, use m repeats of what precedes it (`X`, for example), and then `n-m` appearances of `X?`.  But it would be simpler to refuse to work with `mawk`.  Or write a `mawk` script to convert the regexes?

Comment: Yeah, I'll just check the awk variant. I did a look at the environments where I'll run the script and for instance, they all have GNU awk so I guess we're good.
Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Not a "blind spot": mawk  conforms  to  the POSIX 1003.2 (draft 11.3) definition of the AWK language.  For what it's worth, a quick check of BWK shows it likewise does not provide the feature.

Comment: In a quick check, Solaris 8 and 9 did not appear to implement the feature, nor did Solaris 10.  (A more recent AIX did...) That's well after "1992", based on the system's release dates.  Perhaps it was introduced in the 2004 updates.

Comment: Ah - forgot that Solaris puts standard stuff in /usr/xpg4/bin (which also supports intervals). So 1992 applies (note my comment about BWK though - and read gawk's documentation on the topic).

Comment: @ThomasDickey – [OpenGroup says](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/papers/posix_faq.html) is that, as of ~20y ago, the POSIX 1003.2 standard "has been incorporated into the latest revision of POSIX 1003.1 and thus a POSIX.2 standard no longer exists." The [mawk homepage](https://invisible-island.net/mawk/) links to the older [awk – IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/awk.html), which (like the [current spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04)) specifies full ERE support, including for `{m,n}`.

Answer (score 3):

One of these MAY be what you want:

```
$ cat file
abcbcd
abcbcbcd

$ awk '/(bc){3}/' file
abcbcbcd

$ awk 'gsub(/bc/,"&")>=3' file
abcbcbcd

$ awk 'match($0,/bc/) && (n=RLENGTH) && match($0,/(bc)+/) && ((RLENGTH/n)>=3)' file
abcbcbcd
```

but without sample input and expected output we're just guessing.

Comment: Devious — but there comes a point at which the circumvention is worse than demanding a working `awk`.

Comment: yeah, but we all lived without RE intervals for years before they became available and it just wasn't a big deal. We just need the OP to show us what it is he's trying to do as there's not a one-size fits all solution!