# Awk regex compilation fails: missing operand

Tags: regex, bash, awk, base64

#### Update 1

The issue arises because I am running with **gawk** locally while running with **mawk** in the utility project. As pointed out by Fravadona & explained by Ed Morton gawk is not failing because it silently ignores a mistake I made in the regex.

#### Issue

I want to pipe output of a command to awk but filter for base64 encoded values and mask them. Currently, the code should mask the whole line if a base64 encoded value appears in it.

#### This is my awk-command after the pipe:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[...]          
<some command that outputs a lot to cli> | 
          awk '{
            if (/(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}={2})$/)
                print "[MASKED]"
            else
                print 
          }'
```

#### Yet I get the following error:

```
awk: line 2: regular expression compile failed (missing operand)
(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}={2})$
```

Background info explaining my confusion:

- The above code is located at a utility project and used for all other projects
- The code of the utility project is inside a bash script
- The idea generally works, bc. if I change the regex in the bash script of the utility project to sth. like /'a word that matches'/ I get no error.
- I checked the regex syntax with regex101 regarding missing parenthesis, none are missing

#### If I rebuild the command in the **justfile** of a single project, it works just fine (see example below).

```
   debug:
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
          <some command that outputs a lot to cli> \
          | awk '{
              if (/(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}={2})$/)
                  print "[MASKED]"
              else
                  print
          }'
```

So I guess I am missing sth. quite obvious :( thanks in advance!

Comment: What awk version are you running?

Comment: `(?:)` are not supported by standard ERE engines

Comment: mawk 1.3.4 20200120 in the utility-project vs. GNU Awk 5.2.2, API 3.2, PMA Avon 8-g1, (GNU MPFR 4.2.0-p12, GNU MP 6.2.1)
locally! that might explain a lot

Comment: I think this relates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978495/awk-regex-number-of-repetition-n-doesnt-work-on-mawk-version-1-2 -> the quantification might be the issue (or is at least one)

Comment: Checking a regex in regex101 or any other online tool just proves the regex works on that site, it doesn't mean it'll work in any given command-line tool. You have to learn which regexp variant with which extensions, caveats, delimiters, and options works for the tool you intend to use.

Comment: yes, true. I did not intend to know if it "works", only if I missed parenthesis or anything else, since regex101 nicely highlights them

Comment: are you looking for an explanation of your issue, or a solution that works with both `gawk` and `mawk`?  if you're looking for a solution then consider updating the question with a small sample of `command` output (3-5 lines, 30-40 chars/line, with and without a sample base64 string - can be modified/reduced version of current base64 as long as it matches the desired regex) and the expected output

Comment: I originally was looking for the reason why it failed and wasn't sure about changing the question! But I will do so now and add examples of base64 encoded values that should be detected.

Comment: @Shushiro : I think you may need to tighten the `base64` detection criteria (on top of the `?:` issue) - since the 8 bytes `alphabet` constitute a perfectly valid `base64`-encoded value that decodes out to the 6 bytes of 
`\152\132\141\151\267\255`, so your code might inadvertently capture plenty of data that's already plain `ASCII` text instead of `base64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so in all `gawk` modes except `-P —posix`, this string (strangely) matches that regex criteria :

---

```
?:1234
```

---

```
    # gawk profile, created Tue Aug  8 07:52:15 2023

    # Rule(s)

     1  /(?:[0-9]+)/ { # 1
     1      print
    }
```

but then again, `gawk` is even willing to match a number to a regex with only quantifiers :

---

```
123456789
```

---

```
    # gawk profile, created Tue Aug  8 07:56:16 2023

    # Rule(s)

     1  /?*+/ { # 1
     1      print
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the issue was, that I was not running with the same awk versions in the two scenarios.

**GNU awk** was able to process the regex without errors - **seemlingly avoiding the falsy regex silently** -, while the **utility script runs in a container which as mawk installed.**

Comment: Did you try removing the superfluous (and non-standard) `?:`?

Comment: Regarding "GNU awk was able to process my regex correctly" - absolutely not. It may not give you an error message but there is no awk that will treat your PCRE regexp as you presumably intended.

Comment: In a PCRE `(?:` is the start of a non-capturing group, in an ERE such as all awks use `(?`, with or without a subsequent `:`, is the start of a regexp subexpression followed by a `?` 0-or-1 repetition metachar with nothing preceding it to repeat and so is undefined behavior. Give it's undefined some awks might ignore the `?`, others (e.g. gawk) might treat it as literal, others might print errors but none will subsequently read the `:` and then treat the whole `(?:` as the start of a non-capturing group.

Comment: Whatever awk you're using is deciding to tell you about the issue instead of guessing (and gawk is guessing wrongly in this case) at what you might have meant - it's saying `awk: line 2: regular expression compile failed (missing operand)` because you have a regexp repetition operator `?` with no operand before it for it to operate on.

Comment: For others who might come along, I found this to be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816011/posix-regular-expression-non-capturing-group as well as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816011/posix-regular-expression-non-capturing-group

Comment: that;s the same link twice

Comment: this is the second link https://www.baeldung.com/linux/awk-nawk-gawk-mawk-difference

Comment: @Shushiro : that link is so off base it's not even funny. For starters, claims like "gawk is the only interpreter that supports this new character class of metacharacters. Some of them include, [:alnum:] for alphanumeric characters, [:digit:] for numeric characters, [:alpha:] for alphabetic characters and [:graph:] for non-blank characters." is utterly wrong since `mawk` and `nawk` supported those `POSIX` classes before publication of his/her article

Comment: I did not know that, maybe you can provide a better link?

Comment: Yet I would stop extending this question here further since the original question was answered to quite some extend. If I come up with a solution or better question, I will create a separate one

Comment: @Shushiro : there's no good link that I know of. This one `https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html` is barely acceptable, but still contains non-trivial amount of outdated information. `nawk` also has funny behavior - like you can call `exp()` or `log()` without any arguments, not even the empty string, and nawk will parse `$0` numerically as a substitute input for the function and return its value :::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::   ::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::    `echo 8 | nawk '$++NF = exp()'` ————> `8 2980.96`

Comment: ………..it also reports zero length for the `NULL` byte ::::::: `length("\0") —> 0`, and as a result, empty string is equivalent to `NULL` byte in `nawk`'s eyes : `("" == "\0") —> TRUE` …. and even ***THAT*** is inconsistent, cuz `nawk` thinks `"" ~ /\0\0/` is `FALSE` but `"" ~ /[\0][\0]/` is `TRUE`